# Factorizing non commutative terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization, ncalgebra

Is it possible to factor

```
a ** b ** c - a ** b ** d
```

as

```
a ** b ** (c - d)
```

?

I am using `NCAlgebra`. Using `NCExpand`, we can check that

```
NCExpand[a ** b ** (c - d) == a ** b ** c - a ** b ** d]
(* True *)
```

Note that `a*x - a*y // Factor` or `a*x - a*y // Simplify` return `a*(x-y)`, however.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use `NCCollect` (from the [`NCAlgebra` package](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/master/DOCUMENTATION)):

```
NCCollect[a ** b ** c - a ** b ** d, {a, b}]
(*  a ** b ** (c - d) *)
```