# Simplify expression with non-commutative products

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation, ncalgebra

I am using `NCAlgebra` but I am open to any solution. I would like to simplify some expressions with many terms (a few dozens) using:

- the fact that each term is a scalar (like $v^\top M v$ with $v$ vector and $M$ matrix), hence symmetric;
- the symmetry and skew-symmetry of some variables.

For example, if $v$ is a vector, $M$ a symmetric matrix, $K$ a skew-symmetric matrix,  we may want to simplify $v^\top MKv - v^\top KM v$ as $2v^\top MKv$, because $$\mathbb{R}\ni v^\top KM v = (v^\top KM v)^\top = v^\top M^\top K^\top v = -v^\top M K v.$$

How can I do that in Mathematica ? (below, `tp` is the transpose in `NCAlgebra`)

```
expr = tp[v] ** m ** k ** v - tp[v] ** k ** m ** v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce) to do this. Your assumptions:

```
$Assumptions = v \[Element] Vectors[d] && 
    M \[Element] Matrices[{d,d}, Reals, Symmetric[{1,2}]] &&
    K \[Element] Matrices[{d,d}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1,2}]];
```

Your expression is:

```
expr = v.M.K.v - v.K.M.v;
```

TensorReduce works best with [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct)/[`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract) objects instead of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) objects. Use the ["ToTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToTensor) [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) to convert:

```
t = ResourceFunction["ToTensor"] @ expr
```

> 2 TensorContract[
>     K \[TensorProduct] M \[TensorProduct] v \[TensorProduct] v, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 
>       6}}]

*(Internally, "ToTensor" uses [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce))*. Now, convert back to a [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) representation using ["FromTensor"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FromTensor):

```
r = ResourceFunction["FromTensor"] @ t
```

> 2 v.Transpose[K].M.v

This is basically what you wanted. A further simplification is possible using TensorReduce:

```
TensorReduce[r]
```

> -2 v.K.M.v

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a very convenient tool. The only "issue" I have with this approach is that it does not gather similar terms when the expression is long: `a.r.r.k.r.r.a/(2 n^4) - (4 Cos[n] a.r.r.k.r.r.a)/n^4 - (2 a.r.r.k.r.r.a Sin[n])/n^3` (with  `$Assumptions = 
 a \[Element] Vectors[d] &&  
  k \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals, Symmetric[{1, 2}]] && 
  r \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]] && 
  n \[Element] Reals`). It's basically the same problem I had with `**`, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214043/factorizing-non-commutative-terms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possibility that should work in cases of the expanded form "sum of noncommutative products". It works by extracting each NC product, transposing it, summing al the terms back and comparing the `LeafCount` after having applied the rules for symmetry and skew-symmetry with the `LeafCount` before transposing.

The symmetric variables are `symVars`, the skew-symmetric ones are `skewSymVars`.

```
mySimplify[expr_, symVars_: {}, skewSymVars_: {}] := Block[{level = Level[expr, 1]},
rules = Thread[tp /@ symVars -> symVars]~Join~Thread[tp /@ skewSymVars -> -skewSymVars];
i = 1;
While[i <= Length@level,
 temp = ReplacePart[level, i -> tp[level[[i]]]];
 If[LeafCount@Total@(temp /. rules) < 
   LeafCount@(Total@level /. rules), level = temp];
 i += 1;
 ];
Total@level /. rules
]
```

For the example in the OP:

```
 mySimplify[tp[v] ** m ** k ** v - tp[v] ** k ** m ** v, {m}, {k}]
 (* 2 v^T ** m ** k ** v *)
```

Please do not hesitate to post if you have remarks/better solutions!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single relationship that you would like to enforce

```
tp[v] ** m ** k ** v -> tp[v] ** k ** m ** v
```

then you can apply that as a rule and your expression will simplify. For example:

```
expr = tp[v] ** m ** k ** v - tp[v] ** k ** m ** v
NCReplaceAll[expr, tp[v] ** k ** m ** v -> tp[v] ** m ** k ** v]
```

will evaluate to zero.

However, I suspect that you were hoping for something more generic that would automatically parse all such products and simplify for you. That is a surprisingly difficult task to do with noncommutative algebra. It would require you to normalize the expressions, which could only be done if you have the notion of ordering among your letters. For example, that

```
tp[v] ** b ** a ** v -> tp[v] ** a ** b ** v
```

and not vice versa. That would also require ordering among things like `tp` of a symbol, and so on. You can handle such problems in the context of NC Grobner basis, which are also built in NCAlgebra, but you would first have to define an ordering for your symbols. It might be overkill for what you want to do though. It might be worth it depending on how many such things you would need to simplify.