# NCAlgebra - Factoring common commutative coefficients

Tags: ncalgebra

This is a rather simple question that I cannot quite figure out how to do.
Basically, I have the result of some matrix multiplication in which my resultant matrix has a mixture of commutative and non-commutative symbols.

Is there a way to factor out the commutative symbols automatically? For example, one line in my matrix has non-commuting symbols `e` and `g`, and a constant $\Omega_1$ that commutes with everything.

I have used the following rules

```
SetCommutative[\[CapitalOmega]1, \[CapitalOmega]2, \[CapitalDelta]1, \[CapitalDelta]2]
SetNonCommutative[g, e, r]
DisplayRule = NonCommutativeMultiply[a__] :> Infix[NonCommutativeMultiply[a],"\InvisibleTimes]\[InvisibleTimes]"]
```

Which has allowed me to get NCAlgebra to output the following

$\Omega_1$ (e g) - $\Omega_1$ (g e)

and I would like it to factor to

$\Omega_1$ (e g - g e)

Is it possible to add another rule to get this sort of factorization I would like?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the function `NCCollect` from this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214043/factorizing-non-commutative-terms) which can factor like so

```
NCCollect[a ** b ** c - a ** b ** d, {a, b}]
```

results in

```
a ** b ** (c - d)
```